# Rails 4: Group by Month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails/Ruby, how do I group by and aggregate a measure by month, based on a date column in the table.

I have tried the following technique from Railscasts.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/29-group-by-month

So far, my code look like this

```
result = result.where(transaction_date: start..Date.current)
result = result.select(:transaction_date, :quantity)
result.group_by { |t| t.transaction_date.beginning_of_month }
```

I guess, I need a Ruby equivalent of SQL GROUP BY to rollup the quantity.

The SQLite3 version of what I am looking for is:

```
select strftime('%m', transaction_date)
     , sum(quantity)
from transactions
group by strftime('%m', transaction_date)
```

Comment: Check out section *6 Group* at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#sum

Comment: SQLite3 and PG. I think I should use SQL directly.

Comment: I know it's frowned upon to suggest third-party solutions, but GroupDate does this very, very well and will cover all the bases. https://github.com/ankane/groupdate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this is a good example of why you should use the same database in dev and prod, because you really want to do this in SQL which will be different for the two databases you've specified.  I'll give you the Postgres version.

Assuming your model is called 'Entity' and you're summing an attribute called quantity, you're going to want to do something like this:

```
Entity
  .select("DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) AS month, SUM(quantity) AS total_quantity")
  .group('month')
```

The resulting Entity objects will have virtual attributes 'month' and 'total_quantity' which you can use for your reporting.

Comment: Having two databases was the reason for my apprehension to go the SQL way at first. And, I believe, it is easier to push such processing to the database both from processing and maintenance standpoints.

Comment: Any idea how to go about a group count in this case? ```Entity.select("date_trunc( 'month', created_at ) as month").group('month').count``` raises an error. It also loses `date_trunc` function call and replaces the query with: ```SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, month AS month FROM "entities" GROUP BY month```. This, obviously raises ```ERROR: column "month" does not exist```, as column *month* is virtual.

Comment: Figured this one out. `.count` won't work, but `.select("COUNT(*) AS count, date_trunc(...` will add a virtual attribute `count` on each grouped value in the returned array. This will even preserve Arel constructs before and after `.select[...].group`.